# Internationalization angular application using router

Tags: angular, internationalization, multilingual

I'm trying to make multi language example of angularjs 2 application

I found [ng-2 translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) and using that I can translate my website

**BUT**

How can I do that on language change also changed my url?

for example

> www.domain.com/en/about
>
> www.domain.com/fr/about

and so on

I'm new to angular and one what i thought was that i must make all rout child route of main route which will language but i don't think that it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used ng2-translate and i have used it as used in below plnkr to change the traslation when language change :

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/oMD9pvRrSBcKSzHuRT0b?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: thanks for answer.
I'm too using that sample but using that url is not changing. I want to change it as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using the build in i18n support in angular2: 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html 
I am using it in my project and it works quite well.

Be aware that the ng-xi18n tool might throw some errors and say the process failed, but it really worked and created the messages file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-dynamic-local, using which you can set the language on the fly as per user's choice, like **tmhDynamicLocale.set(langId)**.

Secondly for constructing the routes something like 
    www.domain.com/en/about
    www.domain.com/fr/about
you will need to pass language id as a route param. like
**/:langId/about**. Do let me know if you still have any doubt. Thanks.

Comment: as I found in google it's only for angularjs 1.x I want it for angular2